# How to display data from response in view?

Tags: angular

I have this login component:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Login } from '../model/login'
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login-form',

})
export class LoginComponent {
  data : any;
  // Constructor with injected service
      constructor(
          private loginService: LoginService,
          private router: Router
          ){}

      submitLogin(values){

             var current = this;
             // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
             let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
             loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
             loginOperation.subscribe(
               res => {
                 if(res.isLoggedIn == true){
                    current.router.navigate(['/home']);
                 }
                },
               err => { console.log(err) }

            );
           }


}
```

Now if user is logged in im sending in response data abou user and navigate him to `/home`. In routes i have this:

```
  {path: 'home', component: LogsComponent}
```

This is my LogsComponent:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'home',

})
export class LogsComponent {



}
```

So what i want is to display in home view data from response, something like this:

```
{{ response.user.email }}
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a **shared service** when you want to *share data among components* **OR** for this specific requirement, you can go with **`router parameter`** which is shown in other answer.

**1)** Crate a service.

**SharedService.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular2/core';

export class User{
 name:string,
 email:string
}

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  user:User;
  setUserDetail(res){
   this.user=res;
  }
  getUserDetail(){
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

**2)** **inject** **`SharedService`** in **`appcomponent/rootcompnent`** of the application.

**appModule.ts**

```
import {SharedService} from './SharedService';

@NgModule({
  imports:[...],
  ...

  providers:[SharedService]                    //<<<===here
})
```

**3)** set **`user object`** defined in **`SharedService`**.

```
import {SharedService} from './SharedService';

export class LoginComponent {
  data : any;
  // Constructor with injected service
      constructor(
          private loginService: LoginService,
          private router: Router,
          private ss:SharedService            //<<<====added in constructor
          ){}

      submitLogin(values){

             var current = this;
             // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
             let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
             loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
             loginOperation.subscribe(
               res => {
                 if(res.isLoggedIn == true){
                    //current.router.navigate(['/home']);

                    this.ss.setUserDetail(res); //<<<===assuming res contains name and email.
                 }
                },
               err => { console.log(err) }

            );
           }
}
```

**4)** Get **`user object`** in **`LogsComponent`**

```
import {User} from './SharedService'            //<<<====added

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'home',

})
export class LogsComponent {

 user:User;                                    //<<<====added

 Constructor(ss:SharedService){                //<<<====added
       this.user=ss.getUserDetail();           //<<<====added
 }

}
```

**5)** In view,

```
{{user.email}}
```

***NOTE:*** This might contain some syntax error as this answer is written by hand without copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

What is templateUrl?
templateUrl like this: `templateUrl: './home.html'`
for your question are you send variable to LogsComponent?
you can try:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { Login } from '../model/login'
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login-form',

})
export class LoginComponent {
  data : any;
  // Constructor with injected service
      constructor(
          private loginService: LoginService,
          private router: Router
          ){}

      submitLogin(values){

             var current = this;
             // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
             let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
             loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
             loginOperation.subscribe(
               res => {
                 if(res.isLoggedIn == true){
                    current.router.navigate(['/home'+ res.email]);
                 }
                },
               err => { console.log(err) }

            );
           }


}
```

In routes i have this:

```
  {path: 'home:id', component: LogsComponent}
```

This is my LogsComponent:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',

})
export class LogsComponent {
  private resEmail: any;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
}
  this.route.params
        .subscribe((params) => {
            this.resEmail = params['id'];
        });
}
```

And you should have `home.html`

```
<span>{{resEmail}}</span>
```

Comment: Im getting error here: this.route.params
        .subscribe((params) => {
            this.resEmail = params['id'];
        }); 
unexpected token. a constructor or method or property was expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very comfortable with raw rxjs response as I prefer dealing with promises, but I guess your `res` variable in `submitLogin()` contains data you want to display. A common way to share data between components is to use a service

**LoginComponent** :

```
loginOperation.subscribe(
    res => {
        if(res.isLoggedIn == true){
            LoginService.setUserData(res);                 // store data in `LoginService`
            current.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
    },
    err => { console.log(err) }
);
```

**LoginService**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    ...
    userData: any;
    ...

    setUserData(data: any): void { this.userData = data; }
    getUserData(): any { return this.userData; }
}
```

**LogsComponent** :

```
export class LogsComponent implements OnInit {
    response: any;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.response = this.loginService.getUserData();
    }
}
```

... and now, your `{{ response.user.email }}` should display requested data.